# Drawing particles in a box

Tags: tikz-pgf, physics

I want to draw a figure, somewhat like this:

[image]

Maybe with the left box labeled State 1, and the right box labeled State 2. I searched on how to draw rectangles as  a start, but I could not make much progress from there.

Here is what I have right now:

```
\hspace{4.75cm} \textbf{State 1} \hspace{1.5cm} \textbf{State 2} \\
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
    \draw(0,5)--(0,3)--(2,3)--(2,5);
    \draw(-3, 5)--(-3, 3)--(-1, 3)--(-1, 5);
    \draw (0.5, 3.5) circle(0.2cm);
    \draw (1.5, 4.5) circle(0.2cm);
    \draw (-2.5, 3.5) circle(0.2cm);
    \draw (-1.5, 4.5) circle(0.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place text at any position using `node`s, which can come with shapes like `ellipse`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[egg/.style={ellipse,thick,draw,inner ysep=1.5pt}]
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,2) (2,2) -- (2,0);
\draw (0.7,1.5) node[egg](A) {A} (1.3,0.5) node[egg](B) {B}
(2.7,1.5) node[egg](C) {C} (3.3,0.5) node[egg](D) {D}
(1,2.5) node[font=\bfseries]{State 1} (3,2.5) node[font=\bfseries]{State 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[egg/.style={ellipse,thick,draw,inner ysep=1.5pt}]
\draw[very thick] (0,2) |- (4,0) -- (4,2) (2,2) -- (2,0);
\draw (0.7,1.5) node[egg](A) {A} (1.3,0.5) node[egg](B) {B}
(2.7,1.5) node[egg](C) {C} (3.3,0.5) node[egg](D) {D}
(1,2.5) node[font=\bfseries]{State 1} (3,2.5) node[font=\bfseries]{State 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there any good way to label the diagrams, other than using the \hspace method that I included in my original post?

Comment: @Ekesh Of course, with nodes. Do you want the top line removed like in your example?

Comment: No, I want the top line there please. I am just trying to get labels more efficiently

Comment: @Ekesh I just added both options. BTW, your code is nice, but it would be even nicer if it started with `\documenclass` and ended with `\end{document}`, such that other can just copy the full thing and compile it.